# Angular 6 - *ngFor: appending select option in JSON data

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I'm not sure about the depth of my question.
I'm not even sure my request is possible of or not.

pls check [this  stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fx9evb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

what am trying to achieve is, there is key called 'description' with some paragraph.

In same object structure there is values for select option.

I just want to bind select options on description value.

```
description: "This DummyLoream Ipsum from [currencyType - drop down should come here] [maxRate - drop down should come here] to [currencyType - drop down should come here] [maxRate - drop down should come here] (Loream Ipsum Loream Ipsum Loream Ipsum and Loream Ipsum) and Loream Ipsum-Loream Ipsum Loream Ipsum must be within the Ipsum Loream Ipsum Loream Ipsum Loream, Ipsum Loream Ipsum Loream.All Ipsum Loream.",

dropDownKeysValues: [
        {
          currencyType: "GBP",
          maxRate: "100M"
        },
        {
          currencyType: "USD",
          maxRate: "200M"
        }
      ],
```

Is that really possible?

My idea is about looping through object and getting the indexOf() desired value and then replacing it in drop down.

Unfortunately, I couldn't able to how to start it.

Helps much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: is it this you want? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v6wyzj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: no bro.. actually want to append select option in description text itself. except select option other text are not allowed to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to add a changed event function in order to react on the dropdown by adding (change)="yourFunc" to your select. (in the HTML)

Second, inside that function that is in your component, you loop through the data and replace the value.

Here is your updated [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-worstcoder-example?file=src/app/app.component.ts) I did it only for CurrentCurrency, I think you get the idea.

Comment: that's too close man. value is not getting changed once i change from GDB to USD and vice versa and also. i dont want selection separately. i need use selecting option in description itself. that's what my request. (apologize for my confused question)

Comment: I just corrected the stackblitz, it does now change all the occurrences and also switches back and forth from GDB to USD. But I don't understand what you mean by "I don't want selection separately. I need use selecting option in description itself". You want a drop down in the midst of that text in description? Like "This DummyLoream Ipsum from [a drop down for currency] [a drop down for maxRate]"

Comment: yes yes exactly. thats what my issue and dont know its whether its possible :(

Comment: As far as I know, that's not possible just like that. You can render html from a variable, but you can't bind to it. So you could display a select html tag, but you can't bind to the selected value of that select html tag. However, you could split the description into multiple text fragments and then *ngFor over the fragments and then add the select html tag.

Comment: exactly this is what i consult with my team. but there're not ready change api structure.. but anyways .  you're so awesome man. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a selectedValue. You can directly bind to the object.

```
<div class="form-group" contenteditable="false" *ngFor="let val of mockData">
  <p>{{val.description}}</p>

  <label for="sort" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> select current type </label>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select [(ngModel)]="mockData[0].currencyType" (change)="logMockData()"> 
      <option *ngFor='let item of dropDownKeysValues' [value]="item.currencyType">
        {{ item.currencyType }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <label for="sort" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> select max rate </label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select [(ngModel)]="mockData[0].maxRate" (change)="logMockData()"> 
      <option *ngFor='let item of dropDownKeysValues' [value]="item.maxRate">
        {{item.maxRate}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      name = 'Angular';

      dropDownKeysValues: any = [
            {
              currencyType: "GBP",
              maxRate: "100M"
            },
            {
              currencyType: "USD",
              maxRate: "200M"
            }
          ];

      public mockData: any = [
        {
          id: "{82c6d787-183d-4928-8e67-5ba17dbb0b8b-clni-icm-eo}-{1}",

          createdDate: "12/12/2018",
          createdBy: "Lorieam Ipsum",
          modifiedDate: "",
          modifiedBy: "Ipsum",
          textId: "{pp-ghtter34-5542-998c-12of-gsdfg435as3456nhhc-nopsee}-{1}",
          baseDataid: "{123mkjdfla-234ll234nkjbnjk-234-oop3}-{1}",
          sectionView: {
            id: "{0s0M3-r1And0M-Dat23234}-{1}",
            title: "Lorieam Ispam",
            description: "",
            order: "5"
          },
          title: "This Dummy, Loream Ipsum and Loream Ipsum",
          description: "This DummyLoream Ipsum from [currencyType] [maxRate] to [currencyType] [maxRate] (Loream Ipsum Loream Ipsum Loream Ipsum and Loream Ipsum) and Loream Ipsum-Loream Ipsum Loream Ipsum must be within the Ipsum Loream Ipsum Loream Ipsum Loream, Ipsum Loream Ipsum Loream.All Ipsum Loream.",
          currencyType: "",
          maxRate: "" 
        }


];

      constructor() { }

      logMockData() {
        console.log(this.mockData);
      }
    }
```

Comment: that's actually mock data only for example usage. but in real case am getting data from API. so i cannot change the structure.

Comment: pls see Jeremy's solution above he almost closed to my request

Answer (score -1):

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  public mockData: any = [
    {
      id: "{82c6d787-183d-4928-8e67-5ba17dbb0b8b-clni-icm-eo}-{1}",

      createdDate: "12/12/2018",
      createdBy: "Lorieam Ipsum",
      modifiedDate: "",
      modifiedBy: "Ipsum",
      textId: "{pp-ghtter34-5542-998c-12of-gsdfg435as3456nhhc-nopsee}-{1}",
      baseDataid: "{123mkjdfla-234ll234nkjbnjk-234-oop3}-{1}",
      sectionView: {
        id: "{0s0M3-r1And0M-Dat23234}-{1}",
        title: "Lorieam Ispam",
        description: "",
        order: "5"
      },
      title: "This Dummy, Loream Ipsum and Loream Ipsum",
      description: "This DummyLoream Ipsum from [currencyType] [maxRate] to [currencyType] [maxRate] (Loream Ipsum Loream Ipsum Loream Ipsum and Loream Ipsum) and Loream Ipsum-Loream Ipsum Loream Ipsum must be within the Ipsum Loream Ipsum Loream Ipsum Loream, Ipsum Loream Ipsum Loream.All Ipsum Loream.",
     selectedType: 'GBP',
     selectedcurrency: '100M',
      dropDownKeysValues: [
        {
          currencyType: "GBP",
          maxRate: "100M"
        },
        {
          currencyType: "USD",
          maxRate: "200M"
        }
          ],      
        }
      ];
      selectedValue = 0;
      selectedValue1 = 0;
      public dropDownString;
      public currencyValue;
      constructor() {
       for (var i = 0 ;i<this.mockData.length;i++){     
          this.dropDownString = this.mockData[i].dropDownKeysValues; 
          this.currencyValue = this.mockData[i].dropDownKeysValues;             
        }  
      }
    }



    <div class="form-group" contenteditable="false" *ngFor="let val of mockData">   <p>{{val.description}}</p> <label for="sort" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> select current type </label> <div class="col-sm-4"> <select [(ngModel)]="mockData.selectedType">  <option *ngFor='let d of dropDownString' [value]="d.currencyType"> {{d.currencyType}} </option> </select> </div>


    <label for="sort" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> select max rate </label> <div class="col-sm-4"> <select [(ngModel)]="mockData.selectedcurrency">  <option *ngFor='let c of currencyValue' [value]="c.maxRate"> {{c.maxRate}} </option> </select> </div> </div>
```

Comment: @Sangal Lal i dont why you again paste my stackblitz code here. i dont see any changes.

Comment: please see this [(ngModel)] = "mockData.selectedcurrency"